# Hopfield networks with shared neurons

Tags: neural-networks, capacity, hopfield-network

Has there been research or even a thorough analysis of several Hopfield networks coupled by sets of shared neurons? Would this work? What about their respective storage capacities and robustness? Any hint or reference is welcome.